# Why is this not generating all possible subsets?

Tags: c, recursion, combinations, permutation

I'm trying to generate all possible subsets of a given set. However, this program generates less subsets than all the possible ones. For example, if candidates[] = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 only 25 subsets are printed.
What am I missing?
Also, any ideas on how I can sum each element in each subset and check if the sum is equal to a specific number?
For example, checking which subsets of 1, 2, 3 have elements that sum to 3. (output should be {1, 2} and {3})

I tried modifying a few of the conditions but nothing works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sum.h"
void combinations(int, int, int);

int main()
{
    int i;
    printf("The combinations are:\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= candidatessize; i++)
        combinations(0, 0, i);
}

void combinations(int start, int index, int num_sub)
{
    int i, j;
    if (index - start + 1  ==  num_sub)
    {
        if (num_sub  ==  1)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < candidatessize; i++)
                printf("%u\n", candidates[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            for (j = index; j < candidatessize; j++)
            {
                for (i = start; i < index; i++)
                    printf("%u ", candidates[i]);
                printf("%u\n", candidates[j]);
            }
            if (start != candidatessize - num_sub)
                combinations(start+1, index+1, num_sub);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        combinations(start, index + 1, num_sub);
    }
}
```

(the candidates array and size are declared in a header)

If candidates[] = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
the program should print 31 subsets

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. There are several issues with it. It's unclear what start and index stand for. You've also got a candidates array - is this the input array? If it's not and is an array used to hold subset elements, then you need to add/replace elements in it as you recurse through all combinations. Your recursion logic is also not clear.

Comment: It is rather unclear how this program is supposed to work. Since you are using recursion, you seem to have in mind some way to describe subsets of a set S in terms of subsets of smaller sets. Can you write down your description in English?

Comment: Think about how you calculate the number of subsets: 2^n. I.e. for each of n candidates, you decide if it is in the subset or not (2 possibilitites, n times, hence 2^n). Your code needs to do something similiar.

Answer (score 0):

The number is either displayed (1) or not displayed (0).
To find all 31 (which is 2^5 -1) you can use a 5 bit number
which exactly maps to the number of elements to be displayed. 
like so:

```
/*
arr[5] = {  5,    4,    3,    2,    1   };     
            0     0     0     0     0 
            0     0     0     0     1
            0     0     0     1     0 
            0     0     0     1     1
            ...
            1     1     1     1     1
*/

#include <stdio.h>



int main()
{
    int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    unsigned char x = 1;

    for (; x < 32; x++)                              // run from 2^0 to 2^5 - 1
    {
        if (x & 0x01) printf("%d ", arr[0]);         // extract 2^0 bit     
        if ((x & 0x02) >> 1) printf("%d ", arr[1]);  // extract 2^1 bit
        if ((x & 0x04) >> 2) printf("%d ", arr[2]);  // extract 2^2 bit
        if ((x & 0x08) >> 3) printf("%d ", arr[3]);  // extract 2^3 bit
        if ((x & 0x10) >> 4) printf("%d ", arr[4]);  // extract 2^4 bit
        printf("\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```